# Laravel - Append row id to form name attribute inside each row of a dynamic table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I send two variable to my view `$abilities`, and `$users`. `$abilities` is an array of key-value pairs containing data in the following format:

`["1"=>"create_user","2"=>"delete_user","3"=>"ban_user"]`

`$users` is an array in the following format:

`["1"=>"John Doe","2"=>"Jane Doe"]`

Both are taken from their respective databases `abilities` (columns: ID, name) and `users` (columns: ID, name).

In the view, I have a table which contains a multiple select for each row against the `$user->id`:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
    <td>
       {{Form::select("takenabilities[]",$abilities, null, ['id'=>'system-abilities','multiple','class'=>'form-control' ])}}
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Problem is that when I receive the request in my controller, I only see one `takenabilities[]` array, and I want to save data from each multiple select in each row generated dynamically, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using multiple selects with the same name. The value of the last one overrides all previous selects' values. In addition you'd better assign different `id` to every `select`. Try to add another level to the array:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
    <td>
       {{Form::select("takenabilities[$user->id][]", $abilities, null, ['id'=>'system-abilities-' . $user->id,'multiple','class'=>'form-control' ])}}
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And in controller:

```
$takenabilities = [];
foreach(Request::input('takenabilities') as $userId => $userAbilities) {
    $takenabilities = array_merge($takenabilities, $userAbilities);
}
$takenabilities = array_unique($takenabilities);
```